# R randomForest, unexpected number of predictions

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

I'm training a `randomForest` with 202 observations of 1026 variables. I want to test the prediction accuracy of this forest on a different set of 50 observations. But `predict()` returns a number predictions equal to the size of my training set. Is there something I'm missing here in the below usage? I thought this would use the already-trained forest to predict the `newData`. (Can post more code if necessary but this seems like the only relevant part)

```
dim(trainData)   
#[1] 202 1026   
length(response)  
#[1] 202  
forest<-randomForest(response~., data=trainData)  
dim(testData)  
#[1] 50 1026  
length(predict(forest, newData=testData))  
#[1] 202
```

... Why is this not 50? (the size of `testData`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the capitalization of your parameters:

> length(predict(forest, newData=testData))

Should be

> length(predict(forest, newdata=testData))

It's unfortunate that it doesn't warn you that there was a spelling mistake.  Without the "newdata" parameter, it gives you the prediction of the train set.

Comment: Wow.  Thanks!  After being a developer for years R is still like greek to me sometimes.